# Many php-fpm processes created and they do not go away

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I have PHP (5.5) using Laravel framework on NGINX with PHP-FPM.

Here is what I do. I have a script `myscript.php`

```
<?php
  while(true) {
    @file_get_contents('http://myserver.com/api/data');
  }
?>
```

The API URL, points to a controller in my Laravel app, which roughly does the following :

```
public function getData() {
  $page = file_get_contents('http://an-external-server-page');

  // parse the page and insert some data into Postgres DB
  ...
}
```

Now, on my VPS, I run the script via

```
php myscript &
```

Now after awhile, I type

```
ps -ef | grep php
```

And I see many `php-fpm: pool www` processes.

My assumption is that since I'm running the script once, there should only be a one child process of php-fpm instead of so many. But looks like my assumption is wrong.

My question is, what is creating so many php-fpm requests?

I initially thought php-fpm request is made each time `file_get_contents` is called, but that's not it based on my calculation. For example, I called `file_get_contents` 10 times, but that doesn't mean there are 10 `php-fpm` processes created.

Then I thought maybe some php-fpm requests are created, but not being closed properly. If that's the case, what is the proper way of closing it?

Comment: You are not sending _one_ request, you are sending an _infinite_ number of requests.

Comment: ok, but once the request is received, how do I safely "close" it?

Comment: You don't, PHP does. Try removing the `@` and actually _dealing with_ errors rather than pretending they don't exist.

Comment: ok, so I removed the "@" sign, and I see no errors, but "php-fpm" is still growing.....